# Jquery dialog with Iframe not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, jquery-ui-dialog

Jquery dialog with Iframe not wroking in IE9.

I have an HTML Button on my parent.aspx

```
<input type="button" id="btnMessageFilter" class="mainFont" value="Message Filter"/>
```

On "btnMessageFilter" click, I want to open another aspx page (child.aspx) in Jquery dialog; I was doing this like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnMessageFilter").live('click', function () {
        var iframe = $("<iframe>").attr({
            "src": "MessageFilter.aspx?btn=btnRefresh",
            "height": "100%",
            "marginwidth": "0",
            "marginheight": "0",
            "scrolling": "auto",
            "frameborder": "0"
        });
        $("#dialog2").empty().append(iframe);
        $("#dialog2").dialog({
            modal: true,
            title: 'Message Filter',
            width: 400,
            height: 450
        });
        $("#dialog2").parent().appendTo('form');
        return false;
    });
});
```

The code was works fine except for IE9. Any suggestions to fix the above cod or an alternate way to open another aspx in Jquery Dialog?

Comment: What does `var iframe = $("")` do? Did you mean `var iframe = $("<iframe/>")`?

Comment: yes.. sorry I missed it.. Edited now.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what is wrong with your code. But I use iframes + jQuery-ui dialog on some pages of my website like this:

```
var iframe = $('<iframe frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
var dialog = $("<div></div>").append(iframe).appendTo("body").dialog({
    autoOpen: false, // autoopen is set to false (we'll create only one dialog and open it on-demand)
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    width: "auto",  // set width and
    height: "auto", // height to auto (we'll set width/height on the content)
    close: function() {
        iframe.attr("src", ""); // load blank document in iframe
                                // can be useful in situations, for example,
                                // when your frame is playing audio or video
    }
});
$('#btnMessageFilter').click(function() {
    iframe.attr("width", 400).attr("height", 200); // set width/height on the content
    dialog.dialog("option", "title", "Message Filter").dialog("open");
    iframe.attr("src", "http://example.com");
});
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/bGRNj/6/)

Answer (score 0):

I am replying to this thread as i didn't find the right solution for this problem yet.

To fix this issue make sure that you are setting the "iframe src at the end of your manipulation".

example - in above case src must be set after .dialog() call.